# Which browser versions can run Flash 11.7?

Tags: browser, actionscript, cross-browser, flash

Subject says it all. What are the oldest browser versions that can run Flash 11.7?

These are the versions I need to support for historical reasons, even though I am running HTML5.

Comment: Please don't downvote without a comment, so that I and maybe others have our learning opportunity. Is there something wrong with the question? Does it belong on a different forum? Which?

Comment: I think you got downvoted because this is not a real **programming** question. Also this really could be answered by _googling_ in your favourite search engine. That said, see if my Answer is useful in some way...

Answer (score 1):

All I can add is that most browsers that support NPAPI or ActiveX will run Flash Player 11.7, if that's the browser-installed **Flash Player** plugin version.

**(1)** You can check NPAPI support at the [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) entry :

- Chrome : supported up to version 41 (PC/Mac) | version 34 (Linux)
- Firefox : supported until March 2017.
- IE : should work up to IE 11 (if not higher, but I've not tested). *note:* uses ActiveX for plugins.

**(2)** Flash Player was widely released by [**June 2013**](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_117_air_37_release_notes.html).
Hopefully, installing a browser version from around that date should help you run the content.

Comment: Well, to be precise, I don't need to run the content. I just have a customer who has some old AS content, and their browser requirements specify that as long as a browser can run Flash Player 11.7, the browser is supported by the company. So I need to find which browsers these are, so that I can test my HTML5 code on these versions up.